# PowerPivot % Difference from previous month

Tags: excel, date, pivot-table, powerpivot

When trying to get the percent difference from one month to the next, January (or the first month in the dataset) will always show as blank. How would I go about making Excel look for the previous month of last year?

I am using [DateStream](https://datestream.codeplex.com/) as my date table.

Issues and settings:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Bennett, can you share a sample of your data? Or how your final pivot table looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to add a calculated field to calculate the total for the same period last year...i.e.

TotalSPLY:=CALCULATE(SUM( 'TableName'[Total]), SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR( DateTable[DateKey]))

https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR-Function-DAX-b8f7f423-22f5-470f-abd3-b76a1250bcc1?ui=en-US&rs=en-SG&ad=SG

UPDATE -- (to adhere to the **previous** month from last year requirement)

```
=CALCULATE(SUM( 'TableName'[Total]), DATESBETWEEN( 'DateTable'[DateKey], 

IF( DATE( YEAR( EOMONTH(  MIN( 'DateTable'[DateKey]),-13) ), MONTH( EOMONTH( MIN( 'DateTable'[DateKey]),-13) ), 1 ) < CALCULATE ( MIN( 'DateTable'[DateKey]), ALL('DateTable') ), CALCULATE ( MIN( 'DateTable'[DateKey]), ALL('DateTable') ),             
       DATE( YEAR( EOMONTH(  MIN( 'DateTable'[DateKey]),-13) ), MONTH( EOMONTH( MIN('DateTable'[DateKey]),-13) ), 1 ) ),
IF ( EOMONTH( MIN( 'DateTable'[DateKey]), -13) < EOMONTH( CALCULATE ( MIN( 'DateTable'[DateKey]), ALL('Date') ), 0 ), EOMONTH( CALCULATE ( MIN( 'DateTable'[DateKey]), ALL('DateTable') ), 0 ), 
EOMONTH( MIN( 'DateTable'[DateKey]), -13) ) 
) )
```

Comment: Wouldn't this only compare the same month, just a year back?  Not "December of last year"?